# Install/Run Android Skype on ARM LInux?

Tags: linux, apk, skype, dalvik, arm-processors

I have a Chromebook with an ARM processor. 
I have installed Ubuntu on that Chromebook.

However, since there is no Skype-binary for ARM Linux, is it possible to use the version of Skype of the android APK, and run that on my ARM Linux ?

Is there some kind of Dalvik enviroment or converter for ARM Ubuntu ? 
What would be the minimal emulation environment, if I wanted to emulate android ?

Comment: It's more than just needing Dalvik.  Much of the Android API (such as the whole UI layer) is specific to Android and not available on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

Yes, it's possible. 
Microsoft has release a web-app for skype at
https://web.skype.com

Answer (score 1):

One way to install Linux apps on Ubuntu is through Anbox. It's very resource efficient, using your Ubuntu kernel to run Android apps without emulating the Android kernel or running Android in a VM. However, it's still in alpha, so getting it set up takes a while and apps might crash or not work at all.

Also, you'll need to find the APK somewhere (e.g. APKMirror), as the Play store isn't included.